# How to show human readable NSDate using NSDateFormatter

Tags: objective-c, nsdateformatter

I need to show human readable NSDate localized Format.

Currently, NSDateFormatter can only format one date at a time.

But, I could find any example on how to do two dates format.

Here are some examples of format I need to produce.

1. 10:00 - 11:00AM
   Monday 25th March, 2013
2. 10:00AM - 11:00PM
   Monday 25th March, 2013

and also these need to be in localized format depend on locale and timezone.

Could any one shade some lights here ? Thank you very much.

Comment: Sometimes you have to write your own code.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of how you will approach this, you will have to take two strings and combine them together.

When it boils down to it, you ultimately have two dates:

```
10:00 - 11:00AM Monday 25th March, 2013
^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Date1   Date2
```

You can use two separate `NSDateFormatter` objects to give you what you need.

```
NSDateFormatter *timeOnlyDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
//... set the format for the timeOnlyDateFormatter here
NSDateFormatter *fullDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
//.. set the format for the fullDateFormatter here
```

With this, you can use them to create both the Date1 string and Date2 string, then combine them.

```
NSString *firstString = [timeOnlyDateFormatter stringFromDate:firstDate];
NSString *secondString = [fullDateFormatter stringFromDate:secondDate];
NSString *combined = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", firstString, secondString];
```

There's no real pretty way to do this as far as I know.

Comment: Yes, I think of this solution before, but I stuck with localisation part. The solution above is good when the format is fixed. However, for my case I need to localized it depend on timezone and locale used. So, the format can't be fixed.

Comment: You can change formats based on the locale. You still need to use an NSDateFormatter or roll your own (which is not exactly a simple endeavour)